# Set different time windows and dropping penalties for each vehicle [or-tools]

Tags: python, combinatorics, or-tools, vehicle-routing

In the case of VRP on satellites, each satellite has a different time window over all cities.

I would like to have a time window for each city that is relative to each vehicle. Here is an example with 3 cities:

```
vehicle_1_tw : [0,12] , [11,20], [3,15]
vehicle_1_tw : [9,8] , [4,23], [12,17]
```

Is it possible to implement this kind of constraint in or-tools ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess you mean `vehicle_**0**_tw` for the first one.
2. One possible solution would be to:

   - duplicate the node for each TW,
   - use `routing.VehicleVar(index).SetValue([vehice_index,...])` to limit the node visit to a specific set of vehicles (i.e. vehicles having the same TW).